# ¿Cómo enviar un Intent a un Service?

Tags: android

Tengo este intent:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Servicio.class);
                    serviceIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_BT_DEVICE, btDevice);
                    getApplicationContext().startService(serviceIntent);
```

por alguna razón en el servicio con este código:

```
btDevice = (BluetoothDevice) params.getExtras().get(MainActivity.EXTRA_BT_DEVICE);//btDevice = getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_BT_DEVICE)
```

Dice que es `null` pero no es `null` en el activity.

¿Cómo puedo enviar el dispositivo bluetooth mediante este código?

Comment: Como enviar un intent? no te refieres a un Bundle con datos.

Comment: No, el dispositivo manda los datos con un intent, a no ser que pueda mandar el dispositivo